# How to use socket.io-client in KotlinJS

Tags: node.js, kotlin, socket.io, create-react-kotlin-app

I want to use the socket.io-client library from nodejs in my React-Kotlin project.

I tried to load it like this:

```
@file:JsModule("socket.io-client")
@file:JsNonModule

package modules

@JsName("Manager")
external fun socket(uri: String): dynamic
```

Then client will connect to the server when I call it with this function `val s = socket("http://localhost:8080/")` but when I call an emit like this `s.emit("testemit", mapOf("test" to false))` it doesn't send it.
If I change `s.emit` to something else that does not exist in socket.io-client, I get an error message that the function does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with something like this:

```
val socket = kotlinext.js.require("socket.io-client")("http://localhost:8080/")
socket.emit("testemit", json("test" to false)) { result -> println(result) }
```